# Gridview Rowcommand event firing but show hide controls including Gridview not happening

Tags: c#, asp.net, rowcommand

Here is what I am trying to do in two simple steps:

1) New Row (trNewPost) which has table inside and controls in it to add new post or to update existing post.

```
Default Visible=false;
```

2) Add Button to make above row visible = true;

3) trMyPosts has Gridview in it and displays all the posts.

Default visible = true.

When user click on editing any row of the gridview (RowCommand event) I just want to hide this grid (trMyPosts) and show trNewPost.

That's all. events firing, but nothing happening.

Comment: What technologies are you using? Is this Desktop or browser based? Language? Framework? We need to know more before we can help

Comment: Not a real question? Wow, someone is trigger-happy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got viewstate problem.

One of the things you can do is this :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            // do things here
        }
    }
```

Because whenever anything happens, the page posts back. By encapsulating your `Page_Load` with `! Page.IsPostBack`, you prevent those things from happening over and over again.

Now, if your variable is a global variable, you will have this same problem. Consider instead using a `Session` variable.

Also, I just wanted to show you this piece of code just in case :

```
    protected void HideShowClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // toggle the visibility of the control
        // (that is, if visible then hide, if hidden then show) 
        myControl.Visible = ! myControl.Visible;
    }
```